# Bulk api query - querying last 5 mins

Tags: soql, datetime, bulk-api

I have a requirement to query through bulk api job to fetch records last modified in 5 mins . While Querying I need to utilise lastmodifieddate field of the record .
Note : I can not create another field and utilise that in the query .

So is there a way to query

> select id,name from Lead where LastModifiedDate ..........

I am able to find LAST_N_Days and other date literals but not able to get one for Minutes .
Please let me know if any leads

Comment: You tagged this as Apex but didn't mention the Apex, so I just want to be clear - are you calling the Bulk API from Apex?

Comment: Hey victor ,thanks for replying . I am not calling it from apex .I have removed the tag now .From apex I could create a variable and then achieve this but I have to do it just in the soql with last modified date  field

Comment: I unfortunately think you might be out of luck then.  I checked through the date literals and there doesn't seem to be anything with that level of granularity.  You'll probably have to calculate the value on your end, and I imagine the biggest headache will be making sure the formats match up correctly.